# Asynchronous call via asp.net mvc core controller using the IOC

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc

I’m trying to understand how to speed up long running processes that don’t need to be synchronous.  Think “multiple query results” to display in a dashboard.  I’m using .Net Core with DI and the built in IOC.

I want to call the RequirementsService.Fire() method via the IRequirementsService interface from the Overview() method.  Objective is to  fire off each Fire() method so that the logic for each method call can run simultaneously with the others.  I need to return results to the caller.

The below solution runs synchronous still… I think I have a syntax issue but VS is not bawking at anything, just warning me that it will run synchronously from the Overview() method.

//Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Overview()
    {

        //_requirement service is injected at controller constructor which I removed for brevity.

        var fireOne = await _requirement.Fire(10000, "Fire 1");

        var fireTwo = await _requirement.Fire(5000, "Fire 2");

        var fireThree = await _requirement.Fire(1000, "Fire 3");            

        return View(model);
    }
```

//Interface

```
public interface IRequirementsService
{
    Task<int> Fire(int number, string fireCount);        
}
```

//Service

```
public class RequirementsService : IRequirementsService
{ 

   ...

    public async Task<int> Fire(int number, string fireCount)
    {
        int TimeOne = 0;

         Thread.Sleep(10000 + number);

         TimeOne = (10000 + number)/1000;

        Debug.WriteLine(fireCount + TimeOne);

        return TimeOne;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute your Fire method three times and not have each call successively block the next one, you could do:

```
Task.WaitAll(_requirement.Fire(10000, "Fire 1"),
    _requirement.Fire(5000, "Fire 2"),
    _requirement.Fire(1000, "Fire 3"))
```

Also, use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep to avoid blocking the thread.

Answer (score -1):

Making the **Controller** method to have async nature is not advisible and not a good practise too.How ever you can call async method and combine them in your controller using **WhenAll** method as below

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Overview()
    {

        //_requirement service is injected at controller constructor which I removed for brevity.

        var fireOne = await _requirement.Fire(10000, "Fire 1");

        var fireTwo = await _requirement.Fire(5000, "Fire 2");

        var fireThree = await _requirement.Fire(1000, "Fire 3");            

        ActionResult[] result = await Task.WhenAll(fireOne , fireTwo,fireThree);

        return View(model);
    }
```

I would suggest you with this **[link](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)** for more information on this.

Comment: Why is it inadvisable and bad practice to have an async controller method? Also, you've removed the async modifier on the action, which means he can no longer use await

Comment: if an async call is made, is it mandatory that the calling method must also be async?

Comment: Straight from the compiler error: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.